# I modified the data source of a UITableView on a secondary thread, what is the proper way to update the UITableView so I won't get any errors?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I make several calls to a webservice and receive back a object which I insert into the `NSMutableArray` (which is the table's data source). I do this on a secondary thread. What is the proper way to update the tableview with this new data? I have already tried the basic way with reloadData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -performSelectorOnMainThread: to update the table view on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

from your second thread when you finish updating data source you could tell tableView to reload some of rows with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method of tableView of reload full section with `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` method or even full table view with `reloadData` method

Answer (score 1):

This is what I often do in functions updating UI elements:

```
-(void)functionModifyingUIelements:(id)object
{
 // fire itself in main thread if it is not in it already
 if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) { 

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(functionModifyingUIelements:) withObject:object waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

}
```